# Remove dropdown selection after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a form a user fills in 10 times a day, they select an option from the dropdown then fill in the form and submit. I'm trying to find a way to remove that option once it's been submitted, or highlight it green maybe.

The select dropdown is as follows...

```
<select id="lineDropdown" name="linedropdown">
 <option value="Reflow 2">Reflow 2</option>
 <option value="Reflow 3">Reflow 3</option>
 <option value="Reflow 4">Reflow 4</option>
 <option value="Reflow 5">Reflow 5</option>
 <option value="Reflow 6">Reflow 6</option>
 <option value="Reflow 7">Reflow 7</option>
 <option value="Reflow 8">Reflow 8</option>
 <option value="Reflow 9">Reflow 9</option>
 <option value="Reflow 10">Reflow 10</option>
 <option value="Cam 1">CAM 1</option>
 <option value="Cam 2">CAM 2</option>
</div>
</select>
```

So once they select 'Reflow2' for example, and submit the form. That needs to either be hidden/removed or highlighted with a colour. Then the next day everything back to normal. Can this be done?

Comment: yes this can be done, what have you tried to make it work?

Comment: Nothing as yet because the only related issues I can find ask to keep the selection highlighted after the form submission.

Comment: Here is an option to remove items from a dropdown with javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_remove 
To keep the state of the dropdown until next day: you can store in a cookie the value of the removed dropdown item...

Comment: You need to use db storage for this. When user submit form, you need to save the selected option in database. When user appear again on the form, then you need to fetch saved values from database and need to remove that from select options. Also, you need to make select options dynamically instead of static.  Hope it helps you to finalize the approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for current user which options are already selected
You can save the options in localstorage and while showing options to user don't show options which are already selected

```
    function saveOption(val) {
   var options = localStorage.getItem('options');
   options.push(val);
}
  function filterOptions (opt) {
var options = localStorage.getItem('options');
  return opt.filter((o) => options.indexOf(o) <= 0):
)}
```